# SonarQube Issue Assign feature usage in SonarQube version 5.1

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to use Issue Assign feature of SonarQube 5.1 and configured it to assign all issues to author as determined by the SCM metrics.
I am using SVN 1.6. When I run sonar analysis for a module, Sonar is able to identify issues but unable to assign them.

Please find maven debug information:

```
[DEBUG] [16:31:35.845] Found new issue [afa5355b-16a0-4246-aefa-101e4470db7f]
[DEBUG] [16:31:35.845] Configured auto-assign severity: INFO
[DEBUG] [16:31:35.845] Issue afa5355b-16a0-4246-aefa-101e4470db7f severity: MAJOR
[DEBUG] [16:31:35.845] Issue afa5355b-16a0-4246-aefa-101e4470db7f severe enough to auto-assign: true
[DEBUG] [16:31:35.845] Found resource with key: [src/main/java/com/wcg/calms/xml/util/Persist.java]
[DEBUG] [16:31:35.846] No measure found for metric [authors_by_line] on resource [src/main/java/com/wcg/calms/xml/util/Persist.java]
[WARN] [16:31:35.846] Unable to assign issue [afa5355b-16a0-4246-aefa-101e4470db7f]
```

Could anyone please advise what is wrong? I am not sure how Sonar extracts SCM information from SVN. By the way, my svn and sonar user name are same.

Comment: You've installed the SonarQube Issue Assign plugin, right? With SQ 5.1, this is not required for basic auto-assignement, please read http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Reviewing+Issues#ReviewingIssues-Assigninganissuetoadeveloper. So first, I'd suggest that you remove this plugin. And then can you check if you see the SVN blame information on the source code in SQ.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam I'm running SQ 5.1 and am running into a related issue: The Issue Assign plugin is configurable to only assign issues with priority above a threshold (in my case, Critical). The plugin correctly leaves issues with priority major and below unassigned, but the SQ 5.1 core functionality assigns *all* issues. Can a threshold also be configured on the core functionality? Right now, this pollutes the users workspace, as they should solve their critical issues with priority.

Comment: is issues assign supports SQ5.4 ?

Comment: External Issue Assign plugin is not supported since SQ 5.2 though this feature is built inside SQ since 5.1 onwards with enhanced functionality since SQ 5.2. Check the following url: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Fabrice. I did not install SQ Issue Assign plugin. In fact, SonarQube SVN plugin was missing and therefore I was getting that error. It worked fine after installing SVN plugin.